# How should I switch to new activity from a listview that contains an array of data?

Tags: java, android, mysql

I want to switch to a new activity from the listview that contains an array of data from a mysql database?

File: TampilGambarActivity.java

```
package com.tes.menu;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
//import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
//import android.widget.Toast;

public class TampilkanGambarActivity extends Activity {

    static String in_idmenu = "id_menu";
    static String in_jenismenu = "jenis_menu";
    static String in_image_menu = "image_menu";
    JSONArray str_json = null;
    public String lo_Koneksi,isi ;

    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data_map = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Koneksi lo_Koneksi = new Koneksi();
        isi = lo_Koneksi.isi_koneksi();

        String link_url = isi+"menu.php";
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.AmbilJson(link_url);

        try {
            str_json = json.getJSONArray("menu");

            for(int i = 0; i < str_json.length(); i++){
                JSONObject ar = str_json.getJSONObject(i);

                String id_menu = ar.getString("id_menu");
                String image_menu = ar.getString("image_menu");
                String jenis_menu = ar.getString("jenis_menu");

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(in_idmenu, id_menu);
                map.put(in_image_menu, image_menu);
                map.put(in_jenismenu, jenis_menu);

                data_map.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, data_map);        
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your Listview on Item Click Listener

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

The method should look like this.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                //you can send data here based on the position

}
```

Of course let the class implement the listener, and then within the onItem click use the Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LazyAdapter.class);
                intent.putExtra("hashMap", map);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Get the data from the Second activity

```
Intent  intent = getIntent();
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>)intent.getSerializableExtra("hashMap");
```

Now you have the data in the second activity, use it the same way.

Comment: I've managed to get a picture, but I can not click listview to move to a new activity.